# How to discover if a SAS option or ODS option is set

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I often write general purpose macros in SAS. Within my macro I want to apply some settings, like

- macro variables
- SAS options
- ODS options

But afterwards I want to "clean up my mess".

For a macro variable that would be

```
%macro myMac();
    %let old_mac_var = &mac_var;

    %let mac_var = my_variable;
    %put Doing my stuf with &mac_var.;

    %let mac_var = &old_mac_var;
%mend;

%let mac_var = value before;
%myMac;
%put mac_var is &mac_var;
```

*(Of course I would solve this using a local macro variable in practice, but that's not relevant.)*

But how do I do that for other settings? i.e. how do I complete this code?

```
%macro test_mprint(should_shouldNot);
    data _null_;
        put "NOTE: 'data _null_;' &should_shouldNot. be readable here above in the log";
    run;
%mend;

%macro myMac();
    %let sas_mprint = ...;
    %let ods_exclude = ...;

    options nomprint;
    ods exclude none;

    title 'CARS should be printed because of ods option exclude none';
    proc print data=sashelp.class;
    run;
    %test_mprint(should not);

    options &sas_mprint.;
    ods exclude &ods_exclude.;
%mend;

options mprint;
ods exclude all;
%myMac;

title 'printing CLASS should be avoided by ods option exclude all';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
%test_mprint(should);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAS options are easy to retrieve:

```
%let sas_mprint = %sysfunc(getoption(mprint));  /* gives, eg, NOMPRINT */
```

ODS options am not so sure..

Comment: This is only quarter of an answer.  Retrieving the options is easy, but setting them back the way they were is much harder as there are different 'types' of option settings.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find relevant info in the *RESET=* and *Push and POP* sections from [this SAS help page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/67921/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0kroq43yu0lspn16hk1u4c65lti.htm), which unfortunately apply only to ODS GRAPHICS options.

For resetting the other ODS settings, a sort of hack is exposed [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/SAS-9-3-Resetting-to-initial-quot-ODS-state-quot/td-p/39181).

Comment: Available as of release 9.4 :(